# Why do not display values that I have entered in a database table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Good evening.

I have created a database with ORACLE SQL Developer and am having a small problem.

In the RENTING table that I have created something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE RENTING (cAFM NUMBER NOT NULL, vPlateNumber VARCHAR (7) NOT NULL,
       OutDate DATE, InDate DATE,
PRIMARY KEY (cAFM, vPlateNumber, OutDate),
FOREIGN KEY (cAFM) REFERENCES CUSTOMER (cAFM),
FOREIGN KEY (vPlateNumber) REFERENCES VEHICLE (vPlateNumber));
```

I am trying to enter the following data:

cAFM = 10001, vPlateNumber = 'XKO5434', OutDate = '13 / 07/2020 09:30 ', InDate = '18 / 07/2020 08:00'

I type these commands:

```
INSERT INTO RENTING (cAFM, vPlateNumber, OutDate, InDate)
VALUES (10001, 'XKO5434', TO_DATE ('13 / 07/2020 09:30 ',' DD / MM / YYYY HH24: MI '), TO_DATE ('18 / 07/2020 08:00', 'DD / MM / YYYY HH24: MI '));
```

I get these results:

```
CAFM  VPLATENUMBER   OUTDATE      INDATE
10001    XKO5434     ​​13/07/20    18/07/20
```

without displaying the hours I entered ('09: 30 'and '08: 00').

If anyone could help me I would be grateful.

Comment: Looks like a display issue. Check your SQL Developer preference settings or explicitly format with `to_char()`.

Comment: @jarlh this is Oracle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(indate, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') FROM RENTING
```

It will be fine; the time is there, but your query tool isn't showing it because it's formatting to just the date part

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a0c267946bd451b28edcaeab5e64770d

---

As an aside, when presenting strings for parsing to other forms, strive to be accurate; the spacing of your date strings does not match the spacing of your format string